# Offline Weblogic 12c fails to deploy webservice with MTOM

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, weblogic12c

we have recently experienced a strange behavior when trying to use web service with MTOM.  When Webservice method is annotated *@MTOM*, application fails to deploy with strange message:

**Certificate Alias not supplied**

This happens only on Weblogic that has no access to internet, when we deploy the same application to Weblogic that has internet connection, everything is OK.

We managed to find a note in a forum, saying that this error happens when Weblogic is trying to unsuccessfully access remote resource (like xsd). This might be true because *mtom.xml* file (policy in weblogic) references remote xsd: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization/optimizedmimeserialization-policy.xsd

The webservices are created using standard J2EE 6 annotations (*@WebService*).

Has anyone experience similiar problem? We would appreciate any help.

MF & VH